# Fake mouse scroll using XTest lib

Tags: mouse, x11

How to fake mouse scroll with XTest lib?

Comment: The scroll wheel acts as two additional buttons. Scrolling up is pressing button 4, and scrolling down is pressing button 5.

Comment: Thank you very much n.m., I'm gonna check it out now

Comment: Hi n.m. I'm cheking it, but I can't fake the scroll, I'm using   XTestFakeButtonEvent (dpy, 4, True, CurrentTime);
XTestFakeButtonEvent (dpy, 4, False, CurrentTime); but I can't see the effect. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry n.m., do you meant button 4 and 5 in numpad? Thanks

Comment: It's "mouse button 4" (mouse buttons are numbered), not the key corresponding to "4". If you have xte, try `xte "mouseclick 4"` and `xte "mouseclick 5"`, then check the code paths it runs.

Comment: Thanks pzanoni,you are right, the code is: XTestFakeButtonEvent (dpy, 4, True,  CurrentTime);XTestFakeButtonEvent (dpy, 4, False,  CurrentTime); XSync(dpy, 0);

Comment: The problem I had is a sleep call after XSync. Thanks I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Check the `xte` program and its source code. You might want to use `xte` itself instead of your code.

- http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXtst/

Also, read @n.m. 's comment to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much pzanoni, y really appreciate your help, I'm gonna check it out now